How to use Array with Sumproduct or other formula
I am trying to use an array formula like SUMPRODUCT to perform a lookup with 2 criteria.
I have a sheet named data that stores customer-specific pricing for products.




A
B
C            
D




1
Description
General
Cust A
Cust B


2
Product A
 $ 12.90
 $ 7.90
 $ 8.90


3
Product B
 $ 12.90
 $ 7.90
 $ 8.90


4
Product C
 $ 15.90
 $ 8.90
 $ 9.90


5
Shipping Fee
 $ 15.00
 $ 8.00
 $ 18.00



In other sheets I have my desired result, customer orders, and I want to be able to return the correct pricing based on the specific customer and product.




A
B
C
D
E




1
Customer Name
Cust B





2







3
Item
Description
Qty
Unit Price
Total     


4
1
Product A
3
 $ 8.90
 $ 26.70 


5
2
Product B
5
 $ 8.90
 $ 44.50


6
3
Product C
6
 $ 9.90
 $ 59.40 


7
4
Shipping Fee
1
 $ 18.00
 $ 18.00



I tried to use the following formula to match the correct price with the product and customer but am getting errors.
=SUMPRODUCT(Data!$B$2:$M$31,
   ($B$1=Data!$A$1::$M$1)*
   ($B4=Data!$A$2:$A$31)*
   ISNUMBER(Data!$B$:$M$31))

Link to my sample Google spreadsheet

While a link to a spreadsheet might be helpful, the question should still be self-contained. This means you should describe your spreadsheet's relevant parts and include sample data in the question body.

The question does not explicitly specify what should happen when a customer name cannot be found in the Data table. Presumably, the lookup should default to the General column then?

@doubleunary you are correct (as usual) to flag that.  I have now included error handling in case the options are not limited to valid strings.

Formula
Returns customer-specific pricing for a list of products. I think VLOOKUP with MATCH is a better fit than SUMPRODUCT.
=LET(c,B1, d,Data!A2:D, p,B2:B, 
   INDEX(VLOOKUP(TOCOL(p,1), d,
       MATCH(c, INDEX(d,1),0))))

INDEX  LET  MATCH  TOCOL  VLOOKUP

c stores the customer name.
d stores the Data lookup range
p stores the range of products to look up.

As @doubleunary pointed out in his answer my formula doesn't provide a success path if the customer name is absent or not found.  If you plan to use either a valid customer name or the value "General", such as a data validation drop menu from a helper column, then it isn't an issue.  Otherwise, as they pointed out, it is prudent to add error handling which I did not originally.
Formula w/ error Handling
=LET(c,B1, d,Data!A2:D, p,B2:B, 
   INDEX(VLOOKUP(TOCOL(p,1), d,
       IFNA(MATCH(c, INDEX(d,1), 2), 0))))


If the customer name c cannot be found, IFNA supplies the value 2 which matches the General column.


thanks for helping.
